# Dynamic Rendering of Math Equations using MathJax in Angular 2

Tags: html, angular, math, angular-cli, mathjax

I am building a test engine where the backend code is ready however i am getting stuck with the frontend part.

In the frontend part made using Angular 2 (project setup using angular-cli) I got stuck while rendering the math equations. I am using mathjax and please check what part i am doing wrong. 
Just to clarify, I am able to render the static math equations using typescript however when I take the html string from the backend that is through dynamic loading, it doesn't load properly.

Code:

1. index.html
   Included following two scripts within head tag.

   ```
   MathJax.Hub.Config({
       tex2jax: {
           inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
           processEscapes: true
        }
   });

   cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-
   MML_HTMLorMML
   ```
2. math equation latex

   ```
   \\(2x^2+9y^2=z^3\\)
   ```
3. exam.component.ts

If I use a string like this:

```
this.sample = "math equation latex";
```

and render this in the exam.component.html as {{sample}}, then it works fine. However when I use a http service and get the response, in that case the resulting string it not rendered properly.

Also I read the internet where I found a script to use for dynamic loading involving "typeset", but that doesn't work too.

Please point out what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to add a live sample of what you've tried.